# Domain of function $f(x) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x}$

Tags: calculus, functions

If I had this function:

$$f(x) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x}$$

How do I find the domain of $f(\cos x)$? I've tried but I haven't gotten anywhere. I set $\cos x = 0$ but it's $0$ in infinitely many points, right? I know to find the domain of $f(x)$, though. And there's another question, they are asking if the function $f(\cos x)$ is bounded. I have no idea how to find this either, can anyone help me please?

Comment: When $\cos x=0$ then the numerator and denominator are both $0$, so it's possible the fraction approaches some finite limit.  In some contexts, one might consider that limit to be the value of the function at points where the cosine is zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plug it in, and you'll see that $f(\cos(x)) = \frac {1-\sqrt {1-\cos^2(x)}}{\cos(x)}.$

What we know:

-> Denominator can't be zero. So $x$ can't equal $\frac {\pi}{2}$ (90), $\frac {3\pi}{2}$ (270), and basically - for any integer $n$, $\frac {(2n-1)\pi}{2}$.

-> Square root can't be negative. So $1-\cos^2(x)$ can't be negative. The square will always make the cosine positive, and $ |\cos(x)| \le 1$ so it won't be negative. This can be ignored, then.

Domain is then any number that's not $\frac {(2n-1)\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Use LaTeX if you want your questions/answers readable and clear.

Comment: @DonAntonio How do I do it? As in, do you have an editor or do you just know all the methods?

Comment: Once upon a time there was a FAQ section in this site with directions, @Shahar, but someone thought it'd be a good idea to have people searching for it "on blind". Try in meta or something, I really don't know...or click on "edit" in some answers/questions (if you can, I don't know if you need some minimum of points for this) and see what the commands are.

Comment: @DonAntonio I can click edit. So for example: $f(x) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x}$ But are you sure there isn't some editor or something to make it easier? It seems messy.

Comment: No @Shahar, there isn't...but you get used to this pretty quicly.

Answer (score 2):

$$\text{The domain of} \;\;f(x):=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}x\;\;\text{is}\;\;0\neq|x|\le1\iff [-1,0)\cup(0,1]\;,\;$$

Thus, the domain of $\;f(\cos x)\;$ is

$$\;x\in\Bbb R\;,\;x\neq\frac{2n-1}2\pi\;\iff \bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z}\left(\frac{2n-1}2\pi\;,\;\;\frac{2n+1}2\pi\right)$$

Comment: $\left|x\right|=1$ is allowed here, isn't it? I am talking about the first line of your answer.

Comment: Of course, thanks. Editing on its way.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$ f(\cos(x))=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\cos(x)^2}}{\cos(x)}=\dots. $$

Comment: How is it stil $x$ at the bottom...?

Comment: @DanxMindfreak: it is a typo. now simplify it and try to finish the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $1-\cos^2x=\sin^2x\geq0$

Answer (score 0):

You asked also about the boundedness of $f(\cos x)$.  Since (as in Don Antonio's answer) the domain of $f$ is $[-1,0) \cup (0,1]$ (i.e., the set of $x$ such that $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ and $x \neq 0$) and the cosine function takes all of these values, it is equivalent to ask about the boundedness of $f$.

An important observation is that even though $f$ is not defined at $0$, it can be defined at $0$ so as to be continuous there: i.e., $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ exists.  You can see this by applying L'Hopital's Rule or (better, from a certain perspective) noticing that the limit in question is precisely the derivative of the function $1-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ at $x = 0$, and this function is certainly differentiable at $0$.  (Since the function is even, because it is differentiable at $0$ the derivative must be $0$, but this is not strictly needed in what follows.)

The function $f$ is certainly continuous on its actual domain, so if we extend it to $0$ by putting $f(0) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) (= 0)$, then it is continuous on the closed, bounded interval $[-1,1]$.  By the Extreme Value Theorem, it must be bounded (and attain its minimum and maximum values).